# Error q : Command not found on Vim

Tags: linux, vim, command

I created a bash script :

```
#!/bin/bash 
su root -c vim $1 -c ':%s/^M//g' -c 'wq'
```

My script has to remove all the ^M (carriage return on Windows) on my file, then save it.

When I execute my script it returns :

```
/sequenceFiles/Sequence1.seq: wq: command not found
```

Does someone know why ? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: there is a package called [`tofrodos`](http://www.thefreecountry.com/tofrodos/index.shtml) .. Use `fromdos` out of this package for this

Comment: You might also have utils like `dos2unix`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-c` is seen by `su`, not `vim`, and the shell complains about the unknown command.

You need to pass the command as **one argument** to `su`:

```
su root -c "vim $1 -c ':%s/^M//g' -c 'wq'"
```

Comment: Now, I got a problem : When i'm executing my script, it returns me this error : E486 : Pattern not found. But ^M is present in my file. Why ?

Comment: Vim (on Unix) can detect and handle CR-LF line endings, see `:help 'fileformat'`, that's why there's no `^M` showing, and that also explains the E486. Your question was about the su + Vim invocation error, so please don't unaccept and turn this into a long troubleshooting session! As evidenced by the comments, you shouldn't use Vim, anyway.

Comment: So, what should I use ? Vi instead ?

Comment: I would use the mentioned `fromdos` / `dos2unix` (if you have / can install them), else `sed` (its `s///` is nearly identical; google for a solution if you're not sure); vi / Vim are for interactive editing!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience, you helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`man su` says:

```
`-c COMMAND'
`--command=COMMAND'
     Pass COMMAND, a single command line to run, to the shell with a
     `-c' option instead of starting an interactive shell.
```

Try

```
su root -c "vim $1 -c ':%s/^M//g' -c 'wq'"
```

Answer (score 0):

While you can do it with vim, consider simpler:

```
perl -pi -e 's/\r\n/\n/' file
```